# Getting EOFException while trying to read from SSLSocket

Tags: java, ssl, sockets, eofexception

I am developing a SSL client that will do a simple request to a SSL server and wait for the response. The SSL handshake and the writing goes OK but I can't READ data from the socket. I turned on the debug of java.net.ssl and got the following:

```
[..] 
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1 
[Raw read]: length = 5 0000: 16 03 01 00 20                 .... 
[Raw read]: length = 32 [..] 
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32 Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 32 
[..]
    *** Finished verify_data:  { 29, 1, 139, 226, 25, 1, 96, 254, 176, 51, 206, 35 }
    *** %% Didn't cache non-resumable client session: [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5] [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16 0000: 14 00 00 0C 1D 01 8B E2   19 01 60 FE B0 33 CE 23  ..........`..3.# Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 70 [..]                               a.j.y. 
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 70 
[Raw write]: length = 75 
[..] 
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 70 
[..] 
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 70 
[Raw write]: length = 75 
[..] 
main, received EOFException: ignored main, called closeInternal(false) main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 18 [..] 
ain, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18 [Raw write]: length = 23 
[..] main, called close() 
main, called closeInternal(true) 
main, called close() 
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

The [..] are the certificate chain.

Here is a code snippet:

```
try {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
            /*
             * Set up a key manager for client authentication
             * if asked by the server.  Use the implementation's
             * default TrustStore and secureRandom routines.
             */
            SSLSocketFactory factory = null;
            try {
            SSLContext ctx;
            KeyManagerFactory kmf;
            KeyStore ks;
            char[] passphrase = "importkey".toCharArray();

            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

            ks.load(new FileInputStream("keystore.jks"), passphrase);

            kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

            factory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
            }

            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("server ip", 9999);

            /*
             * send http request
             *
             * See SSLSocketClient.java for more information about why
             * there is a forced handshake here when using PrintWriters.
             */
            SSLSession session = socket.getSession();

            [build query]

            byte[] buff = query.toWire();

            out.write(buff);
            out.flush();

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

            int readBytes = -1;
            int randomLength = 1024;
            byte[] buffer  = new byte[randomLength];
            while((readBytes = input.read(buffer, 0, randomLength)) != -1) {
                LOG.debug("Read: " + new String(buffer));
            }
            input.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I can write multiple times and I don't get any error but the EOFException happens on the first read.

Am I doing something wrong with the socket or with the SSL authentication?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem might be at the server. How is the socket closed there?

Comment: I don't have access to the server. The same request works with a Perl script so the problem is with the Java code I think.

Comment: Create yourself a local Apache instance and configure it to accept SSL connections. A little work, but surely great for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the packet I was sending. The server was getting the packet, checking that it was badly formatted and dropping the connection. Fixing the packet format fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi, how did you exactly fix the packet format? I am having the same problem. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: It was a problem with the packet format of the specific service I was using, not on the SSL format.